# Custom Inline Script with Docusaurus

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I'm trying to add the wowhead tooltips to a [docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/) page.

The [wowhead documentation](https://www.wowhead.com/tooltips) suggests you need to add the following to your `<head>` section:

```
<script>const whTooltips = {colorLinks: true, iconizeLinks: true, renameLinks: true};</script>
<script src="https://wow.zamimg.com/widgets/power.js"></script>
```

I can add the `https://wow.zamimg.com/widgets/power.js` fine using the scripts configuration option which works fine with defer or async:

```js
module.exports = {
  // Snipped rest of configuration
  scripts: [
    {
      src:
        'https://wow.zamimg.com/widgets/power.js',
      defer: true,
    },
  ],
```

For the inline portion `<script>const whTooltips = {colorLinks: true, iconizeLinks: true, renameLinks: true};</script>` I have tried using a `<Head>` component in my index.js `<Layout>` section and had no success.

How can I add this inline script properly to docusaurus so it loads before the wowhead script?

Comment: Try this https://docusaurus.io/docs/lifecycle-apis, I think you need to use the function `injectHtmlTags`.

Comment: using `injectHtmlTags` I am able to inject the two scripts and they load successfully, however now I am having trouble with the library loading the options and it seems to be related to the dynamic content. Running this from the console "updates" everything correctly: `window.$WowheadPower.refreshLinks();`. Any way I can run this after the page has rendered? I can't see a way to do a useEffect() style call with docusaurus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the advice from [D.Kastier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734097/d-kastier), I successfully solved my problem, granted it wasn't very elegant.

To load the script properly, and have it update after the page initially loads:

```
     injectHtmlTags() {
       return {
         headTags: [
           // https://www.wowhead.com/tooltips
           {
             tagName: 'script',
             innerHTML: `
               const whTooltips = {colorLinks: true, iconizeLinks: true, renameLinks: true};

               document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
                 if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
                   console.log('Updating tooltips from plugin');
                   window.$WowheadPower.refreshLinks();
                 }
                });
             `,
           },
           {
             tagName: 'script',
             attributes: {
               defer: true,
               src: 'https://wow.zamimg.com/widgets/power.js',
             },
           },
         ],
       };
     },
```

Then to update the tooltips each time the page changes:

```
    onRouteUpdate({location}) {
      setTimeout(function() {           
          window.$WowheadPower.refreshLinks(); 
        }, 0);
    },
```

Comment: As an aside, I will post another question regarding the best way to run the `window.$WowheadPower.refreshLinks()` after components have loaded & rendered in the docusaurus ecosystem, as that's far outside my docusaurus/react expertise.

Comment: I am happy that I could help! Now I have another hunch: instead of putting the script in the `headTags` try put then in the `postBodyTags`. This will load the script only after the body was created — it may or may not work…

Comment: And/or you could put the script `window.$WowheadPower.refreshLinks();` in the `postBodyTags`

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue either, looks like because this runs before docusaurus properly loads the page content, it doesn't get chance to update the DOM. I'd need a way to run that snippet **after** docusaurus loads the content into `<div id="__docusaurus"></div>`

Comment: Try adding an event listener on the DOM: `document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {if (event.target.readyState === "complete") window.$WowheadPower.refreshLinks();});`

Comment: I can't find any documentation... But I think you will need to use the `onRouteUpdate` to run the script... [See this](https://blogs.thebitx.com/index.php/2021/06/17/update-react-component-state-on-every-route-change-in-docusaurus-by-amrish-kushwaha-jun-2021/) for some light

Comment: Using `onRouteUpdate` works for pages that are navigated to, but only if I wrap the `window.$WowheadPower.refreshLinks();` call in a `setTimeout()` with a 1ms timeout. I added the event listener to the DOM as you suggested and this only runs the first time a page is rendered. Between the two, while I don't fully understand why it's working, it does seem to be working.

Comment: Updated my answer with the solution that loads the script, configures it, refreshes it on page load & subsequent route changes. Thanks for your help @D.Kastier !

Comment: Nicely done! I happy for you, and you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

We can head tag directly in `docusourus.cofig.js`

```json
  headTags: [
    {
      tagName: 'script',
      attributes: {
        type: 'text/javascript',
      },
      innerHTML: `
      console.log('I am JavaScript')
      `
    }
  ],
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly!!